# mpdf generates pdf without images

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I use mpdf for a php project but I am having difficulties generating pdf file with images. it displays the pdf file correctly on browsers but after I save the pdf file it doesnt display the images. I tried it with different browsers/OS and the result is little bit strange to me. it works on very browser and displays local pdf file correctly on linux machine. mac and windows it displays images on every browser but when I save the pdf file it doesnt display the images on local pdf. do you have any idea how to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to use absolute linking, starting all the way at the top with the domain name.

Comment: For future reference this actually is the proper answer although it's a bit bare.